Circular Reference using H2 test mem Quarkus junit 5
I have a this trouble running junit5 test with quarkus:
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:73)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:57)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:263)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:277)
    at io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl$HamcrestAssertionClosure.validate(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy:512)
    at io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl$HamcrestAssertionClosure$validate$1.call(Unknown Source)
    at io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl.validateResponseIfRequired(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy:696)
    at io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl.this$2$validateResponseIfRequired(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PlainObjectMetaMethodSite.doInvoke(PlainObjectMetaMethodSite.java:43)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:198)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:62)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:185)
    at io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl.statusCode(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy:135)
    at io.restassured.specification.ResponseSpecification$statusCode$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl.statusCode(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy:143)
    at io.restassured.internal.ValidatableResponseOptionsImpl.statusCode(ValidatableResponseOptionsImpl.java:89)
    at it.cedacri.signroom.dossier.rest.DossierResourceTest.addDocuments(DossierResourceTest.java:165)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.runExtensionMethod(QuarkusTestExtension.java:1013)
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.interceptTestMethod(QuarkusTestExtension.java:827)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    Suppressed: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "select f1_0.DOCUMENT,f1_0.[*]KEY,f1_0.VALUE from FILENET_INDEXES f1_0 where f1_0.DOCUMENT in (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"; expected "identifier"; SQL statement:
select f1_0.DOCUMENT,f1_0.KEY,f1_0.VALUE from FILENET_INDEXES f1_0 where f1_0.DOCUMENT in (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) [42001-224]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:514)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:489)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getSyntaxError(DbException.java:261)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.readIdentifier(Parser.java:5533)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.readTermObjectDot(Parser.java:4798)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.readTermWithIdentifier(Parser.java:5150)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.readTerm(Parser.java:4834)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.readFactor(Parser.java:3337)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.readSum(Parser.java:3324)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.readConcat(Parser.java:3289)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.readCondition(Parser.java:3079)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.readExpression(Parser.java:2999)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectExpressions(Parser.java:2799)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelect(Parser.java:2817)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parseQueryPrimary(Parser.java:2708)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parseQueryTerm(Parser.java:2564)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parseQueryExpressionBody(Parser.java:2543)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parseQueryExpressionBodyAndEndOfQuery(Parser.java:2536)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parseQueryExpression(Parser.java:2529)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parseQuery(Parser.java:2498)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:627)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:592)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:564)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:483)
        at org.h2.engine.SessionLocal.prepareLocal(SessionLocal.java:639)
        at org.h2.engine.SessionLocal.prepareCommand(SessionLocal.java:559)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1166)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:93)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:316)
        at io.agroal.pool.wrapper.ConnectionWrapper.prepareStatement(ConnectionWrapper.java:658)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:150)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:177)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:152)
        at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.lambda$list$0(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:102)
        at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.DeferredResultSetAccess.executeQuery(DeferredResultSetAccess.java:226)
        at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.DeferredResultSetAccess.getResultSet(DeferredResultSetAccess.java:163)
        at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.advanceNext(JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.java:254)
        at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.processNext(JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.java:134)
        at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.AbstractJdbcValues.next(AbstractJdbcValues.java:19)
        at org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.RowProcessingStateStandardImpl.next(RowProcessingStateStandardImpl.java:66)
        at org.hibernate.sql.results.spi.ListResultsConsumer.consume(ListResultsConsumer.java:178)
        at org.hibernate.sql.results.spi.ListResultsConsumer.consume(ListResultsConsumer.java:33)
        at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.doExecuteQuery(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:361)
        at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.executeQuery(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:168)
        at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.list(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:93)
        at org.hibernate.sql.exec.spi.JdbcSelectExecutor.list(JdbcSelectExecutor.java:31)
        at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.MultiKeyLoadChunker.processChunk(MultiKeyLoadChunker.java:152)
        at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.MultiKeyLoadChunker.processChunks(MultiKeyLoadChunker.java:97)
        at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.CollectionBatchLoaderInPredicate.initializeKeys(CollectionBatchLoaderInPredicate.java:161)
        at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.CollectionBatchLoaderInPredicate.load(CollectionBatchLoaderInPredicate.java:123)
        at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:680)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:75)
        at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:127)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:1702)
        at org.hibernate.collection.spi.AbstractPersistentCollection.lambda$initialize$3(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:617)
        at org.hibernate.collection.spi.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:265)
        at org.hibernate.collection.spi.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:615)
        at org.hibernate.collection.spi.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:136)
        at org.hibernate.collection.spi.AbstractPersistentCollection.lambda$readSize$0(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:163)
        at org.hibernate.collection.spi.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:265)
        at org.hibernate.collection.spi.AbstractPersistentCollection.readSize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:148)
        at org.hibernate.collection.spi.PersistentMap.size(PersistentMap.java:130)
        at it.cedacri.signroom.dossier.rest.DossierMapper.copyUsingMapMergeAndAvoidValueCollision(DossierMapper.java:53)
        at it.cedacri.signroom.dossier.rest.DossierMapperImpl.documentsToDocumentDtoOutput(DossierMapperImpl.java:213)
        at it.cedacri.signroom.dossier.rest.DossierMapperImpl.documentsListToDocumentDtoOutputList(DossierMapperImpl.java:333)
        at it.cedacri.signroom.dossier.rest.DossierMapperImpl.dossierTodossierDto(DossierMapperImpl.java:182)
        at it.cedacri.signroom.dossier.rest.DossierMapperImpl_ClientProxy.dossierTodossierDto(Unknown Source)
        at it.cedacri.signroom.dossier.rest.DossierResource.addDocuments(DossierResource.java:162)
        at it.cedacri.signroom.dossier.rest.DossierResource_Subclass.addDocuments$$superforward(Unknown Source)
        at it.cedacri.signroom.dossier.rest.DossierResource_Subclass$$function$$2.apply(Unknown Source)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceed(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:73)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceed(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:62)
        at io.quarkus.hibernate.validator.runtime.interceptor.AbstractMethodValidationInterceptor.validateMethodInvocation(AbstractMethodValidationInterceptor.java:71)
        at io.quarkus.hibernate.validator.runtime.jaxrs.ResteasyReactiveEndPointValidationInterceptor.validateMethodInvocation(ResteasyReactiveEndPointValidationInterceptor.java:21)
        at io.quarkus.hibernate.validator.runtime.jaxrs.ResteasyReactiveEndPointValidationInterceptor_Bean.intercept(Unknown Source)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InterceptorInvocation.invoke(InterceptorInvocation.java:42)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.perform(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:30)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InvocationContexts.performAroundInvoke(InvocationContexts.java:27)
        at it.cedacri.signroom.dossier.rest.DossierResource_Subclass.addDocuments(Unknown Source)
        at it.cedacri.signroom.dossier.rest.DossierResource_ClientProxy.addDocuments(Unknown Source)
        at it.cedacri.signroom.dossier.rest.DossierResource$quarkusrestinvoker$addDocuments_b7afbe93d75250dd7a3b11c32408e2702f167df6.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.handlers.InvocationHandler.handle(InvocationHandler.java:29)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.server.runtime.QuarkusResteasyReactiveRequestContext.invokeHandler(QuarkusResteasyReactiveRequestContext.java:141)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.common.core.AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.run(AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.java:147)
        at io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder$14.runWith(VertxCoreRecorder.java:582)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2513)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1538)
        at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
        at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
    Suppressed: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement [Syntax error in SQL statement "select f1_0.DOCUMENT,f1_0.[*]KEY,f1_0.VALUE from FILENET_INDEXES f1_0 where f1_0.DOCUMENT in (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"; expected "identifier"; SQL statement:
select f1_0.DOCUMENT,f1_0.KEY,f1_0.VALUE from FILENET_INDEXES f1_0 where f1_0.DOCUMENT in (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) [42001-224]] [select f1_0.DOCUMENT,f1_0.KEY,f1_0.VALUE from FILENET_INDEXES f1_0 where f1_0.DOCUMENT in (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)]
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:64)
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:56)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:108)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:187)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:152)
        at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.lambda$list$0(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:102)
        at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.DeferredResultSetAccess.executeQuery(DeferredResultSetAccess.java:226)
        at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.DeferredResultSetAccess.getResultSet(DeferredResultSetAccess.java:163)
        at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.advanceNext(JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.java:254)
        at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.processNext(JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.java:134)
        at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.AbstractJdbcValues.next(AbstractJdbcValues.java:19)
        at org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.RowProcessingStateStandardImpl.next(RowProcessingStateStandardImpl.java:66)
        at org.hibernate.sql.results.spi.ListResultsConsumer.consume(ListResultsConsumer.java:178)
        at org.hibernate.sql.results.spi.ListResultsConsumer.consume(ListResultsConsumer.java:33)
        at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.doExecuteQuery(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:361)
        at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.executeQuery(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:168)
        at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.list(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:93)
        at org.hibernate.sql.exec.spi.JdbcSelectExecutor.list(JdbcSelectExecutor.java:31)
        at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.MultiKeyLoadChunker.processChunk(MultiKeyLoadChunker.java:152)
        at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.MultiKeyLoadChunker.processChunks(MultiKeyLoadChunker.java:97)
        at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.CollectionBatchLoaderInPredicate.initializeKeys(CollectionBatchLoaderInPredicate.java:161)
        at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.CollectionBatchLoaderInPredicate.load(CollectionBatchLoaderInPredicate.java:123)
        at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:680)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:75)
        at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:127)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:1702)
        at org.hibernate.collection.spi.AbstractPersistentCollection.lambda$initialize$3(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:617)
        at org.hibernate.collection.spi.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:265)
        at org.hibernate.collection.spi.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:615)
        at org.hibernate.collection.spi.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:136)
        at org.hibernate.collection.spi.AbstractPersistentCollection.lambda$readSize$0(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:163)
        at org.hibernate.collection.spi.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:265)
        at org.hibernate.collection.spi.AbstractPersistentCollection.readSize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:148)
        at org.hibernate.collection.spi.PersistentMap.size(PersistentMap.java:130)
        at it.cedacri.signroom.dossier.rest.DossierMapper.copyUsingMapMergeAndAvoidValueCollision(DossierMapper.java:53)
        at it.cedacri.signroom.dossier.rest.DossierMapperImpl.documentsToDocumentDtoOutput(DossierMapperImpl.java:213)
        at it.cedacri.signroom.dossier.rest.DossierMapperImpl.documentsListToDocumentDtoOutputList(DossierMapperImpl.java:333)
        at it.cedacri.signroom.dossier.rest.DossierMapperImpl.dossierTodossierDto(DossierMapperImpl.java:182)
        at it.cedacri.signroom.dossier.rest.DossierMapperImpl_ClientProxy.dossierTodossierDto(Unknown Source)
        at it.cedacri.signroom.dossier.rest.DossierResource.addDocuments(DossierResource.java:162)
        at it.cedacri.signroom.dossier.rest.DossierResource_Subclass.addDocuments$$superforward(Unknown Source)
        at it.cedacri.signroom.dossier.rest.DossierResource_Subclass$$function$$2.apply(Unknown Source)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceed(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:73)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceed(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:62)
        at io.quarkus.hibernate.validator.runtime.interceptor.AbstractMethodValidationInterceptor.validateMethodInvocation(AbstractMethodValidationInterceptor.java:71)
        at io.quarkus.hibernate.validator.runtime.jaxrs.ResteasyReactiveEndPointValidationInterceptor.validateMethodInvocation(ResteasyReactiveEndPointValidationInterceptor.java:21)
        at io.quarkus.hibernate.validator.runtime.jaxrs.ResteasyReactiveEndPointValidationInterceptor_Bean.intercept(Unknown Source)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InterceptorInvocation.invoke(InterceptorInvocation.java:42)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.perform(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:30)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InvocationContexts.performAroundInvoke(InvocationContexts.java:27)
        at it.cedacri.signroom.dossier.rest.DossierResource_Subclass.addDocuments(Unknown Source)
        at it.cedacri.signroom.dossier.rest.DossierResource_ClientProxy.addDocuments(Unknown Source)
        at it.cedacri.signroom.dossier.rest.DossierResource$quarkusrestinvoker$addDocuments_b7afbe93d75250dd7a3b11c32408e2702f167df6.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.handlers.InvocationHandler.handle(InvocationHandler.java:29)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.server.runtime.QuarkusResteasyReactiveRequestContext.invokeHandler(QuarkusResteasyReactiveRequestContext.java:141)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.common.core.AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.run(AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.java:147)
        at io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder$14.runWith(VertxCoreRecorder.java:582)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2513)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1538)
        at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
        at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
    Caused by: [CIRCULAR REFERENCE: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "select f1_0.DOCUMENT,f1_0.[*]KEY,f1_0.VALUE from FILENET_INDEXES f1_0 where f1_0.DOCUMENT in (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"; expected "identifier"; SQL statement:
select f1_0.DOCUMENT,f1_0.KEY,f1_0.VALUE from FILENET_INDEXES f1_0 where f1_0.DOCUMENT in (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) [42001-224]]

What does mean CIRCULAR REFERENCE: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "select f1_0.DOCUMENT,f1_0.[*]KEY....?
this not happens using Oracle Jbcd driver.
FILENET_INDEXES is an ElementCollections Map:
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name = "FILENET_INDEXES",joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "DOCUMENT", referencedColumnName = "DOCUMENT_ID" )})
@MapKeyColumn(name = "KEY")
@Column(name = "VALUE")
Map<String, String> filenetIndexes = new HashMap<>();

dependencies tree:
+- io.quarkus:quarkus-jdbc-h2:jar:3.6.9:test
[INFO] |  +- com.h2database:h2:jar:2.2.224:test
[INFO] |  \- org.locationtech.jts:jts-core:jar:1.17.0:test

Quarkus version is 3.6.9
How can i resolve this problem?

You may be able to avoid H2 and test and develop directly against Oracle Express, using Dev Services: https://quarkus.io/guides/databases-dev-services

I found it
In the connection string missing the NON_KEYWORDS=KEY,VALUE
jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;NON_KEYWORDS=VALUE,NAME,DOCUMENT,SEQUENCE,KEY
